# How to get value of Get-DisplayResolution and pass as an environment variable into nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell

I need to get the screen resolution of the desktop environment to then pass as an environment variable to nodejs.

Say my resolution is 2880x1620 and i then did the following

```
$resolution = Get-DisplayResolution
$env:SCREEN_RES="$resolution"
```

The output would just be a single character, "2".

No matter what I try, the value is always "2"

Comment: Assuming that the cmdlet (which only exists on Server Core editions of Windows Server) returns `2880x1620` as a _string_, there is no explanation for your symptom. I suspect the problem is in a part of the code you're not showing.